# Extremely long import times from Excel File to SQL Server Management Studio using Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, excel

I have been importing an excel file with approximately 250,000 rows of data and 40 columns to SSMS on a weekly basis through the Import Wizard. Unfortunately, the import times take around 45 minutes, which is a bit longer than I would like.

The main issue I am facing is that I am not able to access SSIS or use BulkInsert queries due to a client restriction. I am left with trying to import using the Import Wizard exclusively.

Are there any tricks I could try to maybe make the import run faster? The server I am on itself doesn't have much RAM so could that also be a limiting factor?

I have tried saving as a CSV and importing, but get a flow task error informing me that the import data did not match the target destination type. This is because I have a number of columns specified as datetime or int. Is there a way around this without having to edit each column in the advanced area for selecting my flat file source?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the excel file to a .csv and importing that instead?  I find that larger excel files are much more cumbersome to interact with, and converting your input file to a .csv may improve overall performance as it won't need to go through the Jet driver.

Comment: You probably want to [merge your two accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use BCP? A CSV export and a BCP import should do the trick as well.  Alternately, you import the CSV into a staging table, and manipulate the data inside SQL Server before sending it to its final destination.